# Facebook PHP SDK event wall posts limit and pagination

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

Hi I created an app to load facebook event "wall posts" and "attending list" into a searchable form for use by door staff as a guestlist.

Recently it won't pull more than 10 posts from an events wall posts.

I've been playing about on the open graph explorer and have ran into the same problem. I can't get it to display more than ten results.

Why does it paginate now and why even if I add "since" and "until" parameters to the call does it still only display the last 10 posts on the wall?

If anyone could help me remove the pagination and get all results at once that would be magical!

Here's my call in my php:

```
$event_id = intval($_GET['id']);
$comments_id = '/' . $event_id . '/feed?fields=id,from,message';
$guestlist = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', $comments_id ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->getPropertyAsArray('data');
$i = 0; while($guestlist[$i]) {
echo $guestlist[$i]->getProperty('from')->getProperty('name');
echo nl2br($guestlist[$i]->getProperty('message'));
$i++;
}
```

Here's an example of an open graph request:

```
941122979255816/feed?fields=id,from,message
```

Here's an example facebook event:

facebook.com/events/941122979255816/

Here's my app:

events.sawhost.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: Still scratching my head over this. I cant seem to get the open graph explorer to let me browse thorough all the wall posts, just 10

Answer (score 0):

It seems that facebook is having some pagination issues. I guess all we can do is sit tight while they fix it

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/809829259052996/